How to mirror TCP connections in nginx free version
Using nginx free version, on receiving a tcp connection request, is it possible to broadcast connection to list of backend servers simultaneously using streams module.
Could find below post for http connection
Is there a way to configure Nginx to broadcast incoming requests to multiple upstream servers simultaneously?
Looking for something similar for mirroring L4 traffic.
We tried integrating nginx with socat and it worked with one upstream servers, but with two upstream server it didn't work.
